# How to use the value of an input in a div using classes

Tags: jquery

I want to show the value of a text input in another element. There are multiple instances of this code on the page, so I want to select the items using classes rather than ID.

Problem is I can't select the h2 using `this`.

Here is a simplified version:

HTML:

```
<div class="block">
  <h2>Text to be replaced</h2>
  <div class="block__content">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="candidate-name">Name of Candidate</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('input').on("input", function() {
  $(this).closest('h2').text($(this).val());
});
```

It works if I take out `this`, so I know the rest of the function is correct, so I think it's a problem with `this`:

```
$('input').on("input", function() {
  $('h2').text($(this).val());
});
```

But I want to select the nearest h2 so I don't affect all the others.

Is something wrong with how I am using `this`?

Thanks

Comment: No the problem is 'closest', It is not meant to do what you are doing. Closest is to find the first parent element that matches the criteria. You need .prev(). https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: Thanks, `prev` does in fact work in my example, but in reality the h2 is two levels up in the tree, so I think `closest` is the right choice?

Comment: I have updated the HTML to reflect the nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.closest()` gets you the closest *parent*. the `h2` element you're trying to select isn't a direct parent of the input, but a *sibling of a parent*.

You could get the [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) `.block` element and then access the `h2` [child](https://api.jquery.com/children/).

e.g.

```js
$('input').on("input", function() {
  $(this).closest('.block').children('h2').text($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <h2>Text to be replaced</h2>
  <div class="block__content">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="candidate-name">Name of Candidate</label>
      <input type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! And you're explanation really helped!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this works for accessibility.

Also the nested divs will be annoying to remove when you style your form with CSS Grid.

Make sure the form makes sense semantically and consider using a different element for the heading, unless it really is a heading don't use it. Forms have fieldsets and legends if you want to mark them up. H2 might not be the heading level really desired.

But you want your form to be pretty. What you can do is use pseudo-selectors and put them together in javascript to have contents equal to the heading you want to show. Forms - even big forms should be simple and normally a sign of it getting hacky is a sign that the UX is going wrong.

It is okay to markup the form with labels that are hidden on some screen sizes. If you are using HTML 5 form elements with placeholders then this is fine. The assistive technology folks still get their labels.

So, not the answer you wanted, but, keep the form simple and easy to maintain. Style it responsively with CSS Grid. Use pseudo-selectors for decorative elements. Make sure it is accessible (and simple). You will then find the scripting easier, not even needing jQuery but just selectors in vanilla JS.

Comment: I don't even know where to start with this. Thanks for taking the time, but there are so many assumptions and unrelated advice.